# The procedure entry point_gxx_personality_sj0 could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\sfm\sfml\sfm-graphics-d-2.dll

Tags: windows, dll, mingw, codeblocks, sfml

I am trying to install SFML(2.5.1) in CODEBLOCK(20.03) with and currently using windows 8.1. I have downloaded *sfml-tdm-sjlj-32* bit as per the tutorials that I saw in the web. I did all the set-ups and declared all the linkers properly but unfortunately it gave me error asking for **libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll** not found so I downloaded it and added to my CODEBLOCK environment. After doing so I build and debugged a code that I got from SFML::CODEBLOCK tutorial just to test it but it gives me the following error -

*The procedure entry point_gxx_personality_sj0 could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\sfm\sfml\sfm-graphics-d-2.dll*

thank you in advance :)

Comment: Don't mix gcc exception models. Your environment probably uses Dward and now you want to use a library compiled with a GCC that uses SJLJ. Even if you get it to link it's likely to crash if there is any C++ code in there. Best is to use SFML compiled with the same compiler the rest of your environment uses, or even build it from source.

Comment: @BrechtSanders you are a genius. Thanks you sir ,yes my environment was using dw2.After installing sfml dw2 it started  working. I was just misguided by the tutorial.

Comment: Ok, I will put my comment as an answer, so you can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix gcc exception models. Your environment probably uses Dwarf and now you want to use a library compiled with a GCC that uses SJLJ. Even if you get it to link it's likely to crash if there is any C++ code in there. Best is to use SFML compiled with the same compiler the rest of your environment uses, or even build it from source.